# How can i change directionality on tinymce

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, textarea, tinymce-4, tinymce-5

I'm using tinymce in my project but i dont know why my text area working reverse. Directionality came right to left. But i want to use left to right. I add directionality:"ltr" but it doesnt work. What can i do ? Where is my mistake ? Thanks for help! My Code :

```
<Editor
              onChange={EditorDataUpdate}
              apiKey="SOMEKEY"
              onInit={(evt, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)}
              initialValue={editorData}
              init={{
                directionality: "ltr", //Still working like rtl
                menubar: false,
                plugins: [
                  "advlist  autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                  "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                  "table contextmenu textcolor paste fullpage textcolor",
                ],
                toolbar:
                  "undo redo | formatselect | " +
                  "bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter " +
                  "alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | " +
                  "removeformat | help",
                content_style:
                  "body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px ;min-height:200px;}",
              }}
            />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add `directionality` as a plugin to editor:

```
 init={{
        plugins: ["directionality"],
      }}
```

Then with `directionality` property of `init`, you can set the default value of `direction`:

```
 init={{
        plugins: ["directionality"],
        directionality: "ltr",
      }}
```

Also you can add `directionality` plugin to toolbar same as this:

```
init={{
        plugins: ["directionality"],
        directionality: "ltr",
        toolbar: "rtl ltr" 
     }}
```

Finally, here's the full example:

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import { Editor } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";

export default function App() {
  const editorRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <>
      <Editor
        onInit={(evt, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)}
        initialValue={"<p>This is the initial content of the editor.</p>"}
        init={{
          height: 500,
          menubar: false,
          directionality: "ltr",
          plugins: [
            "directionality advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount"
          ],
          toolbar:
            "rtl ltr | undo redo | formatselect | " +
            "bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter " +
            "alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | " +
            "removeformat | help",
          content_style:
            "body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }"
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit zen-euler-ir94g]

Comment: Thank you for response! I think my problem isnt rtl. Becouse i did exactly same but its still same. After i type a letter focus is going to before first letter. So when i write "stackoverflow" its being like "wolfrevokcats" I thought its becouse of rtl but i think its not. So how can i solve it ? Do you know why its being like that ?

For example : https://prnt.sc/1wtsu7u

Comment: @NewinXamarin Have you tried to change the keyboard language?

Comment: no but my keyboard is already turkish. So my language is ltr. I think its not about that but thank you for your replies! <3

Comment: @NewinXamarin That's allright! Have your problem solved?

Comment: Yes brother. Finally i found my problem. Its a bug i guess. When i change onChange to onBlur its works well. Problem is from onChange event. Maybe i did something wrong for it im not sure yet but i start using it with onBlur now hahaha.